# How to connect to several cassandra clusters at same time with Spring Boot Starter Data Cassandra

Tags: spring, cassandra, spring-boot-starter

I need to connect to different cassandra clusters depended on input data. I have idea how to achieve that with manually creating *cassandraTemplate* for each cluster. but what about **spring-boot-starter-data-cassandra**? Does it allow achieve same behavior?